Recommendation letter for Ph.D. in Mathematics
I am going to graduate with my Master's in math, and I want to pursue my Ph.D. abroad. I would like some suggestions involving "Letter of recommendation" to enhance my chance in getting to the university.
I asked professors from my department (3 of them including my advisor). One of them (not my advisor) told me that she is willing to write it for me, but she thought that it might be not strong since she only knew me as a committee of my thesis defense. Actually, I met her during a few conferences that I did oral presentations of my work, so I think her letter should be strong even though I haven't take classes she taught. In fact, I think she has never taught on graduate level during my Master's. She is an expert in the field I'm interested, albeit with slightly different subfield, and I think her opinion in the letter might be strong.
Is it okay to have a recommendation letter from whom we didn't study with, especially in my situation?
Is it better that I should request the letter from another professor I took class in? In this case, I attended a class of another professor and did quite a good job (as I think, since I disccused with him further from the class). I believe he might be okay to write it for me, but during the class he expressed no interests in the field I will be applying, so I send a request and talk with the first professor above beforehand.

If a professor tells you they can't write a strong letter believe them. Professors know what a strong letter is and what a weak letter is. A weak letter will look bad with graduate committees.

@CameronWilliams She concerned about the familiarity. So, the graduate committees concern seriously on the familiarity of the recommenders?

Echoing a comment, if she tells you it won't be strong, it won't be strong enough. It isn't personal familiarity, which is mostly worthless in letters, but familiarity with your work and how you go about it. How do you overcome difficulties, etc.
The letter needs to be an honest and confident prediction of your success in doctoral study and beyond. If she says she can't make that prediction, then you should look to someone who can.
